# How can I transfer a file from linux server to windows server 2003 using ssh?

Tags: windows-server-2003, ftp, linux, sftp

I want to transfer data from my linux(Debian) server to windows server 2003.I have a ftp of windows server and SSH access of linux server .
I do not want to do manual transfer using upload and download using ftp.
Is there any way,so I can directly transfer file from linux remote server to windows server using ssh?

Note * I do have any public url in linux server.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use PSCP from Putty http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Answer (score 1):

Try scp or rsync. WinSCP is a windows implementation of scp.

Comment: install WINSCP on windows and then login to your nix box with it.
http://winscp.net/eng/index.php

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand what you mean by "I do not want to do manual transfer..". If you don't want to use FTP, you can connect to Linux server from Windows server using [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/) which is equivalent to scp from Linux to Linux.

Comment: I do not want to download from linux to my local system and than upload from my local system to window server using ftp client.